# rosbag play monitoring?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i want to monitor rosbag play it means when rosbag is reading and sending each part of rosbag i want to take it and use it in may source ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59508/rosbag-play-monitoring?/) by [MMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/1271/mmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for but you can use rosbag programmaticaly by using the API. http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/rosbag/html/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0